# I want to get number of user logged in to salesforce with specific profile

Tags: apex, soql, batch, query, login-history

I want to get number of users logged into salesforce in every 30 minutes for specific profile.
LoginHistory doesn't provide profilename/Id ,how can I achieve this

Answer (score 2):

In these situations, it helps to know which fields you do have access to. The SOAP API documentation is where I tend to turn to. In the [SOAP API docs for LoginHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm), we see that there is a `UserId` field, which is a reference to `User`.

`User` does contain `ProfileId`, which is what you're after.

So your query's `WHERE` clause would look something like `WHERE User.ProfileId = '<target profile id here>'` or `WHERE User.Profile.Name = '<Profile name here>'`

### +edit:

At least that would be the case if it were a normal relationship field.
Turns out that Salesforce treats this particular field differently, and you can't do the normal thing (removing 'Id', and using dot notation).

In this case, you'll need to use a semi-join
`WHERE UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE User.Profile.Name = '<target profile name here>')`

You could also base your query on the User object `Select Id FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserId FROM LoginHistory WHERE LoginTime >= 2020-09-25T09:30:00-05:00)`

Additional work will be needed to determine if the user is *still* logged in (going based on time only gives you new logins, not continued sessions or sessions that have since been logged out). The main point is that you can use a semi-join.

Comment: Based on above, SOQL should be something like select userid from loginhistory  WHERE userid in (select id from user where User.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')

Comment: @Swetha At first, I thought that was unnecessary, but a bit of testing revealed that it is. Good catch.